# "Nullable object must have a value" when Mapping bool? to bool?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

In my app, I fetch two attributes `IsLoopCar` and `LoopStatusSet` from a DB and Store them to a model class:

```
 private static ChecklistModel MapChecklistModel(DataRow row)
        {
            var checklist = new ChecklistModel
            {
                 IsLoopCar = Convert.IsDBNull(row["IsLoopCar"]) ? null : Convert.ToBoolean(row["IsLoopCar"]),
                LoopStatusSet = Convert.IsDBNull(row["LoopStatusSet"]) ? null : Convert.ToBoolean(row["LoopStatusSet"])
            }
        }
```

In my model class and the viewModel I map my model class to, the data type of these two attributes is bool?

```
public class ChecklistModel
    {
        public bool? IsLoopCar { get; set; }

        public bool? LoopStatusSet { get; set; }
    }

public class GetPaymentInformationViewModel
    {
        public bool? IsLoopCar { get; set; }

        public bool? LoopStatusSet { get; set; }
    }
```

The value of the attribute in my DB is `null`. When I map the model to the viewmodel using AutoMapper (7.0.1), I get an error message which I don't understand:

```
GetPaymentInformationViewModel gpivm = _mapper.Map<ChecklistModel, GetPaymentInformationViewModel>(checklist);
```

The mapping configuration is very basic:

```
CreateMap<ChecklistModel, GetPaymentInformationViewModel>();
```

The error message is:

> InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.

I don't understand what's the point in mapping nullable bools, when they have to have a value. I need to have this value to be null when i pass it to the view because it works as kind of a checkpoint where the user must select a yes/no value with no initial default value set.

Comment: AM 7 is a long time ago :) Upgrade.

Comment: Just tried 10.1.1 with the same effect :-( I'll try to dive into automapper a little deeper but that part of the app is some legacy stuff that I inherited from my predecessor.

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the recommendation of Lucian, I tried to reproduce the problem with a fresh console app but it didn't fail there. As it turned out, the problem was in my view model where I had written a custom setter that makes no sense:

```
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "IsLoopCar")]
        public bool? IsLoopCar 
        { 
            get
            {
                return _IsLoopCar;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value.Value == true)
                    _IsLoopCar = value.Value;
                else
                {
                    _IsLoopCar = value.Value;
                    LoopStatusSet = null;
                }
            }
        }
```

The field value.Value cannot be read because it does not exists. It's supposed to be like that:

```
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "IsLoopCar")]
        public bool? IsLoopCar 
        { 
            get
            {
                return _IsLoopCar;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == true)
                    _IsLoopCar = value;
                else
                {
                    _IsLoopCar = value;
                    LoopStatusSet = null;
                }
            }
        }
```